# How to detect whether a plugin or script has already been loaded without using eval() or requireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, eval, instance

I'm working on a plugin that allows to inject 3rd party code into a page (either as `iframe` or directly into the DOM).

My problem is "direct injections", because I need to make sure, I don't add any <scripts> additional times, if they are needed in my main page and in a page I'm loading and injecting.

For example (and I can't use requireJS), my `page.html` looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/js" src="jquery.js"></script> // exports window.$
   <script type="text/js" src="foo.js"></script>    // exports window.foo 
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- things that make foo load anotherPage.html and append its content here -->
  </body>
 </html>
```

with `anotherPage.html`

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/js" src="foo.js"></script>    // exports window.foo 
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- stuff that also runs on FOO -->
  </body>
 </html>
```

Page loading is done via Ajax and when I'm processing the `data` returned by my request for `anotherPage.html` I end up with a list of all elements after doing this:

```
    cleanedString = ajaxResponseData
        .replace(priv.removeJSComments, "")
        .replace(priv.removeHTMLComments,"")
        .replace(priv.removeLineBreaks, "")
        .replace(priv.removeWhiteSpace, " ")
        .replace(priv.removeWhiteSpaceBetweenElements, "><");
    // this will return a list with head and body elements
    // e.g. [meta, title, link, p, div, script.foo]
    content = $.parseHTML(cleanedString, true);
    // insert into DOM
    someTarget.append(content);
```

This is where I'm stuck trying to detect whether a script I'm about to append to the document is already there.

I cannot go by the `src`, because the filename may differ and a script may be hosted on a different domain (with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` correctly set). I also don't know, what and if the script I'm about to append returns a global I already have defined and I can't/don't want to use `eval()` to find out.

**Question**:
Is there any way to identify whether a plugin or script that may return a global is already "on" a page, when I only have the "non-appended" <script> element available?

Thanks!

Comment: if(self.$ && self.foo){ do stuff; }

Comment: hm. sounds too easy. let me try.

Comment: you can even make it wait: (function wait(){ if(!self.$){return setTimeout(wait, 100);}; do Stuff()  }());

Comment: but what if I don't know `foo` by name? In requireJs, I would know my module `foo.js` exports `foo`, so when the module is being re-requested it will not be loaded again.

Comment: my pattern would not double-load something that's there. essentially, it's an exploded and simplified version of what requireJS et al do, and you can modify it to make it DRYer for your needs; i'll be glad to lend a hand if a can.

Comment: @dandavis: would be cool, if you could help out. Let me see how far I get with your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of my self-enclosed module pattern, i call it a "Sentinel":

```
 (function wait(){ 

   if(!self.$){
       if(!wait.waitingJQ){
             wait.waitingJQ=true;
             addScriptTag(JQUERY_URL); 
       }
       return setTimeout(wait, 44);
   } 

   doStuffThatNeedsJquery();

 }());
```

The sentinel pattern work from anywhere (internal or external), doesn't care about script loading order, and works with ANY script loading library. you can list additional depends below the jQuery fork in the same manner, just put your greedy code at the bottom of the sentinel wrapper function.

Comment: re: cmt. yes, you need a smoking gun from each script file to use this. since you alluding to each script providing a depends, you should be able to reach/sniff that dependency from your page. Worst case, you can append a smoking gun to a custom script file for semi-invisible scripts like polyfills.